# "Conquistas profissionais" ou "Conquista profissional" para uma conquista num CV?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Se eu quero mencionar apenas uma conquista profissional num CV, numa seção separada, como devo chamar a seção? "Conquista profissional" ou "Conquistas profissionais"?

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta refere-se à forma de um curriculum vitae, e você está em dúvida se deve usar o singular ou o plural, no título de uma relação que pode conter um ou muitos ítens. Por exemplo: participações em congressos, estágios, realizações profissionais, palestras, cursos ministrados, conquistas profissionais, trabalhos publicados, etc. Todos esses ítens podem conter uma ou muitas participações suas. **Mesmo que você tenha só uma hoje, o título deve vir no plural pois entende-se que, com o tempo, você acrescentará muitas outras.**

A exceção seria "experiência profissional", onde eu entendo como sendo a soma de todos os ítens.  Nesse caso eu deixaria o título no singular.

Answer (score 0):

Conquista profissional soa estranho para mim, tanto no singular quanto no plural.  Talvez você queria dizer "experiência profissional".

Comment: Eu queria dizer realização/realizações/sucesso/êxito ... entendeu? :)

Comment: Independente de se "conquistas/realizações profissionais" ou "estágios" ou "apresentações em congressos", sendo um título, melhor usar no plural.  Você pode ter só um hoje, mas com o tempo certamente terá muitos outros para citar.

Comment: Conquista profissional é diferente de experiência profissional.

Comment: Obrigada, pessoal!!